Where should I ask questions about Microsoft Power Platform? (Power Apps, Power BI, Power Automate)
My first choice would be SharePoint SE (because SharePoint is commonly the back-end for Power Apps) but my questions are specific to Power Platform, not SharePoint. My second would be Stack Overflow as the default for programming questions. A search of the SE sites doesn't reveal anything specific to Azure, the Cloud, or Power Platform.
Update: I had to modify my question because it was closed as a duplicate. That was not correct. The question that my question is being compared to is about multi-platform apps.
Respectfully, there is a big difference between a multi-platform app, which is an app that runs on different platforms (like Windows/Mac or Apple/Android); and the Microsoft Power Platform, which is a suite of applications in Azure cloud. They both have "platform" in the title, but they are totally different things.
Secondly, since someone asked for the specific question, I am asking more in a general sense where I should pose ANY questions about the Power Platform. I might have a question about configuring Teams and Security roles in an Environment; or I might have a question about programming in a Power Apps application. I do not see a cloud-specific or Azure-specific or Microsoft-specific group within SE. I generally would ask in SharePoint SE if it was a Power Apps programming question, because that's the closest that I can think of. But my question was about configuration. So since I don't know every single community in SE intimately, I would rather someone point me in the right direction so I don't waste people's time in a community where no one is asking or answering these sort of questions.

It appears there are tags for power platform or similar in all three groups. I didn't think to search tags, I just searched questions and got too many responses to sort out.

My first instinct was web apps.se mainly because it is unclear if you have a programming question about Power Apps or a usage question. That said, web apps is riddled with Google-Apps questions but not a single Power App question (unless you count the one tagged with power-automate). Without your actual question that you plan to ask, it is hard to give correct guidance.  See the Keep in Mind section of the tag wiki.

Please provide the question you want to ask (as the [site-recommendation] tag suggests). Without it, there is no one right answer.

For what it's worth, Stack Overflow does have many power-automate questions, as well as ~20,000 powerbi questions. That being said, many of these are probably technically off-topic there as they're not about programming/writing code.
If your question involves writing code, it's probably OK on Stack Overflow.
If your question is in any way interfacing with content on a SharePoint Online site, it's technically OK to ask about on SharePoint.SE.
If your question is about using a Power Apps tool that can be used in a desktop/offline configuration, like Power BI Desktop, it's probably OK to ask on Superuser.
If your question doesn't involve SharePoint or code, and isn't about a desktop application like PowerBI Desktop, then Web Applications.SE is probably the safest bet.
If you think there ought to be one site on the network where you can ask any question about the Power Apps platform, the appropriate avenue would be to try and get one created via Area 51, but fair warning: that is a rather big task.

There is no site on Stack Exchange where ANY question about Microsoft Power Platform is on-topic, although there are sites where some questions might be on-topic.
List of Stack Exchange Sites - Technology: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-questionsperday

Platform-specific sites like Sharepoint Stack Exchange are not common on Stack Exchange, most sites are not platform specific, i.e.,

Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
Server Fault is for system administrator questions.
Super User is for computer user questions

Stack Exchange sites might have limitations and exclusions, i.e., Super User doesn't allow questions about web applications, mobile applications, etc.
Note: Site scopes are not exclusive, meaning some sites might overlap. However, cross-posting across Stack Exchange sites is discouraged (a cross-posted question might be closed).
